# How do I save the name of a path in photoshop?

Tags: path, pen-tool

I now have a pen path called "working path" in the right-hand panel. How can I change the name so that I can save it?

Comment: Greetings! Tried clicking on it? It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images. Saves everyone time, and increases the chances that you will get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Double-click it in the **Paths Panel** or choose `Save Path` from the Path Panel menu.

[image]

[Basic Photoshop Tutorials](http://sixrevisions.com/graphics-design/35-basic-tutorials-to-get-you-started-with-photoshop/)

Comment: I was able to name it but I'm not sure if it's saved. Where is the path panel menu? I'm using CS6 and when I right-click the path name my options are duplicate path, delete path, make selection, fill path, stroke path, and new 3D extrusion from selected path.

Answer (score -2):

This video should help, I had the same problem!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXrCCi2A2DE

Comment: Hi Ihadthesameissue, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!